# Permanently remove "Xbox Live Auth Manager"

Tags: windows-10, uninstall

There is a task running on my 64-bit Windows 10 machine called "Service Host: Xbox Live Auth Manager". I want to permanently remove this component from my system. If I try to end the task, I get the warning that ending it will cause Windows to become "unusable". How can I get rid of this component?

Comment: To disable the three Xbox services, if you set them to **Disabled**, they will be unable to start.  Have you tried that?  Make sure they are not already in a **Stopped** state.  However, you are not going to be able to remove the services themselves, the best you can do, is make it so only user intervention can start it.  By doing this, each time you logged into your user, Windows will complain the service couldn't be started.